# Adding a full-width image to a Bootstrap 3 row/column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 grid.

I need to add a header image that's 960 pixels wide.

However, if I add it to a row, the usual padding of 10px on a column "offsets" my image since it no longer "fits":

[image]

I know how to *force* this to work, but I was wondering if I am missing some modifier class in BS3 to make this work.

And, yes, I know I could use a css background-image but the client wants an image there.

Comment: have you tried a basic negative margin-left:-10px ; or a position:relative + left:-10px ?

Comment: yes, as I said, I can FORCE it to work, my question was whether Bootstrap has a class for this purpose that I have overlooked.

Comment: take away you col something class and give it a row class  wich has no margin nor padding i believe . you give no code , so funny guess ;)  does this reading will help http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: `"if I add it to a row, the usual padding of 10px on a column "offsets" my image"` actually if you add 100% width image directly under `row` then you can have full width image no problem. Whereas if you are adding image to wide column  `col-sm-12`, then _the column_ will have padding and your image would be offset. So simply add image directly to `row`, without nesting it within `col-*-12`. And according to my investigations there's no problem putting full-width image to row, but i couldn't figure out how to use full- _column_ image (unless you put on image `width: calc(100% +30px);`

Comment: this is a problem I've encountered many times with bootstrap - as mentioned you basically have two options:

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your CSS that removes the margin to make full-width image within the column and then add that class after the column.

```
.bosom-none {
    margin-right: -15px; // Removes the right gap
    margin-left: -15px;  // Removes the left gap
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="colum-md-6 bosom-none">
            <img src="your-image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Biddingger couldn't make this work. Looks as if it may work, but it only removes left margin. But image doesn't stretch to the right edge. And even if you add to `.bosom-none { width: 100%; }` it still won't work, because image width in pixels is calculated _before_ the `left-` and `right-margin` is applied. Which means that if the column width is 130px, then  100% image would be calculated as 100px (which makes sense if you want to have 2 15px margins on sides). But then `margin-left: -15` simply moves image to the left. But `margin-right: -15;` does nothing. You get 30px gap on right

Comment: Biddinger was close. What helped me was just set the padding-left and -right to 0 of that bosom-none. Negative-Margin just messed it up :)

Comment: You can add width:calc(100% + 30px) to your bosom-none class

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something else messing it up because as you can see, a container, row and then a img gives you no margins.

```
<div class="container" style="background:green">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dBNwq/1

Here's the whole page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="background:green;">
            <div class="row">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/960x150">
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background:red;">
                Some other content
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're not using Bootstrap 3 here at all, just straight html.  so, yes, of course it works. Please read the question.

Comment: Just use `container-fluid` instead.

Comment: Only columns (`.col-*-*`) may be children of `.row`s

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've encountered many times with Bootstrap. You basically have three options:

- If you're placing the image inside a column (e.g. `.col-sm-12`) which is inside a `.row`, you'll have to apply a negative margin to the image or a parent container equal to the column's padding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEGkaQ
- You could also instead make the image (or a wrapping `div`) a direct child of the `.row` but [Bootstrap discouraged use to do this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro).
- You can move the image outside the .col/.row all together, give it it's own .container and rid of that container's padding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGvAap.

I usually go for option #1.

Please note that this does not answer your question. It meant to write this for future reference for other people encountering the same problem and do not know how to *force* this to work.

The actual answer to your question: no, Bootstrap does not offer such a modifier class.

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace div class="container" with div class="container-fluid"

and that's it !

Comment: the .container-fluid makes your entire application 100% wide instead of applying a max-width and making it centered (.container). This is unrelated to the issue mentioned where content is being contained by a padded column

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a class that will cover the container it is in...

```
.heroLg {
    size:cover;
    -webkit-size: cover;
    -moz-size: cover;
    -o-size: cover;
}
```

Then add the class to your image.

Comment: I think you mean background-size and this only applies to background images, not IMG elements

Answer (score -2):

put the image into a span12

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="span12">
         <img src="image.jpg" />
     </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 has removed span12 in exchange of col-md-12 and the likes. Read the question. -1